# Freeze_support what is needed?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Am I understand correctly, that `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` need only to compile .py script to .exe in windows? Or is it used in other things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understand correctly.

According to documentation, this method only needed to maintain the `multiprocessing` module in working condition under frozen exe under Windows.